# How to launch an Android background service written in Rust?

Tags: android, rust

I have written a small service that opens up a `TcpListener` and accepts connections on it. This service should be run as background service on an Android device (API level > 23).

This is the code for the Rust part:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn connect() {
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:9000".parse().expect("");
    let mut listener: TcpListener = TcpListener::bind(addr).expect("");

    let mut poll = Poll::new().expect("");
    let mut events = Events::with_capacity(128);

    poll.registry()
        .register(&mut listener, Token(0), Interest::READABLE)
        .expect("");

    loop {
        poll.poll(&mut events, None).expect("");

        for e in &events {
            match e.token() {
                Token(0) => loop {
                    match listener.accept() {
                        Ok((mut socket, address)) => {
                            socket.write(b"Hello, Client").expect("");
                            println!("Got connection from {}", address);
                        }
                        _ => {}
                    }
                },
                _ => {}
            }
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(target_os = "android")]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub mod android {
    extern crate jni;

    use self::jni::objects::{JClass, JString};
    use self::jni::sys::jstring;
    use self::jni::JNIEnv;
    use super::*;

    #[no_mangle]
    pub unsafe extern "C" fn Java_com_example_service_BackgroundService_start(
        env: JNIEnv,
        _: JClass,
    ) {
        connect();
    }
}
```

There is no specific reason to use `mio` except that it is supposed to work with Android. This will be compiled with the 'aarch64-linux-android' target.

On the Android side, there is a `MainActivity` that launches the background service, which is called inside a class of its own:

`MainActivity`

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        System.out.println("starting service...");
        startService(new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class));
        System.out.println("service started.");
    }

    // added
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

`BackgroundService`

```java
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

    static {
        try {
            // load native lib
            System.loadLibrary("lpadapter");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    // entry point of native service
    public static native void start();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

and all the settings from the 'AndroidManifest.xml'

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.example.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".service.BackgroundService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

After a successful build, the app installs seamlessly, and `adb logcat` displays all logs as seen above. Unfortunately, there is no open port.

What am I missing? This [blog entry](https://robertohuertas.com/2019/06/29/android_foreground_services/) mentions a different approach due to changed Android requirements.

Comment: How did you determine that port is closed?

Comment: simple port scanning either with `nmap`or `netcat`. is there any other way?

Comment: Afair, there's a netcat inside android emulator, you may try to connect internally from `adb shell`, smth like `nc localhost 9000`